# How do i integrate luis api (intent and utterances ) to search sharepoint docs?

Tags: sharepoint, nlp, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I have created  LUIS utterances and intents and also published them after training.
I got the app id and key ,i tested using the endpoint url https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/xxxxxxxxxxxx?verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&subscription-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&q=Search

But i got a message in browser that :  App not published in this region. Please re-train and republish your application.

And also want to integrate sharepoint api and  finally test via bot emulator.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

In query string add the property "&staging=true" and check.
Try to explore Graph API to get documents from SharePoint.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0